# Saving images on external hard drive

Tags: python, urllib

I have a simple loop to download a large number of images (1,5 million). The images itself are small, but I estimated that the total size will be 250 GB, which is too much for my HDD.

I got an external HDD, but even though the code runs without errors, the designated image folder is empty! 
I tried the same code for a direction on my internal HDD and it works fine, slowly retrieving the images. Interestingly, the code reads the .csv file from the external HDD, so reading seems to not problem.

Any idea what I could do?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import urllib

# change paths and dependencies:
file_name = "ID_with_image_links.csv"
file_path = "/Volumes/Extreme SSD/"
path_for_images = "/Volumes/Extreme SSD/images"


os.chdir(file_path)
df  = pd.read_csv(file_name)
total_len = len(df)
os.chdir(path_for_images)
df = df.head(10)  # this is for try-out
n = 1

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        id = str(row['ID'])
        im_num = str(row["Image Number"])
        link = str(row["Links"])
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, (id + "_" + im_num + ".jpg"))
        print("Image", n, "of ", total_len, "downloaded")
        n = n +1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the directory writable. I figure you are using macOS?

You can set the directories rights to read/write by using `chmod  666 /Volumes/Extreme SSD/images/` on the terminal as root.

At least on BSD (and macOS is based on that) mounting an external drive is read only by default IIRC.